# joining two tables by value of one column and calculating

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

Thank you for interested in question.
I have in one table some thing like this

```
sifrez | sifKorisnikPK | Status
  1    |    1          |  'P'
  2    |    1          |  'P'
  3    |    1          |  'U'
  4    |    2          |  'P'
  5    |    2          |  'P'
  6    |    2          |  'U'
  7    |    2          |  'U'
  8    |    3          |  'U'
  9    |    3          |  'U'
  10   |    3          |  'U'
  11   |    3          |  'U'
  12   |    4          |  'P'
  13   |    4          |  'P'
```

Then i created stored function which count values of P and U search ratio between them find user with that id and return username

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getBestUsernames
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    SELECT SifKorisnikPK, COUNT (Status) AS BrojLosih
    INTO #LosaRez
    FROM Rezervacija 
    WHERE Status = 'P'
    GROUP BY SifKorisnikPK
    order by count(*) desc
```

After this part it give me

```
sifKorisnikPK | BrojLosih
       1      |    2
       2      |    2
       4      |    2
```

This only count p on status.
And this:

```
SELECT SifKorisnikPK, COUNT (Status) AS BrojDobrih
INTO #DobraRez
FROM Rezervacija 
WHERE Status = 'U'
GROUP BY SifKorisnikPK
order by count(*) desc
```

i get

```
sifKorisnikPK | BrojDobrih
     1        |    1
     2        |    2
     3        |    4
```

Only count U. This part work like a charm...
And here i try to join this two temp tables and calculate ratio and return SifKorisnik with best ratio

```
SELECT Username FROM Korisnik   
    WHERE SifKorisnik = (SELECT TOP 1 a.SifKorisnikPK 
                         FROM #DobraRez a   
                         INNER JOIN #LosaRez b  
                         ON a.SifKorisnikPK = b.SifKorisnikPK OR 
                         a.SifKorisnikPK != b.SifKorisnikPK     
                         WHERE a.BrojDobrih - b.BrojLosih > 0   
                         ORDER BY a.BrojDobrih - b.BrojLosih ) 
    END
```

And after joining operation i expect to get some thing like this, which i'm not getting

sifKorisnikPK | BrojDobrih | BrojLosih
    1          |  1         |     2
    2          |  2         |     2
    3          |  4         |     0
    4          |  0         |     2

so i can calculate the ratio BrojDobrih - BrojLosih and return the SifKorisnikPK which is the best ratio. In this case it would be SifKorisnik 3.
But my procedure get SifKorisnik 2 which is second best. I presume that the problem is in joining operation that it doesn't input 0. So how can i solve this?

Comment: @NepaliRookie sql server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   A.sifKorisnikPK,
   IsNull(BrojDobrih,0) BrojDobrih,
   IsNull(BrojLosih,0) BrojLosih
FROM (select distinct sifKorisnikPK from Rezervacija) A
LEFT JOIN #LosaRez B
   ON A.sifKorisnikPK = B.sifKorisnikPK 
LEFT JOIN #DobraRez C
   ON A.sifKorisnikPK  = C.sifKorisnikPK 
ORDER BY (IsNull(BrojDobrih,0) - IsNull(BrojLosih,0))
```

Comment: Easier then. Please look if the query solves your problem. I believe it does.

Comment: Yap it does. Thank YOU very much!